# create a grid on 2D array and count values

Tags: python, arrays, image, grid

Hy everyone,

I'm working with astronomical fits image. From the fits file, I had this 2D image / 2D numpy array.

[image]

My goal is first to create a grid (as I drew manually above, for example), than, from every cell of that grid, counting the values inside it. The size of the box must be fixed at 25x25 pixel.

I'm confused about what is the best way to do that. I was wondering if there is a way using `pyregion` or maybe `geopandas` (which I am less familiar with). Any suggestion or examples are welcome!

With `pyregion` I am able to draw a specific, let's say, sqared region, and then calculate the counts inside it one at a time... but what would be perfect is to do all at once and than create a map of the count in each cell.

Comment: if you have `numpy.array` then simply replace pixels with green color using `for`-loop - it doesn't need any other module to draw it. Eventually you can use `pillow` or `openCV` to draw on images. And you have to calculate in some cell then simply get this region `arr[y1:y2, x1:x2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `numpy.array` then you could use `cv2.rectangle` to draw grid.

```
img_grid = cv2.rectangle(img_grid, (x, y, BOX_W+1, BOX_H+1), GREEN)
```

You can do it in `for`-loop.

```
for y in range(0, height, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, width, BOX_W):
        img_grid = cv2.rectangle(img_grid, (x, y, BOX_W+1, BOX_H+1), GREEN)
```

I use `cv2` also to load image and save image.

```
import cv2

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)  # BGR instead of RGB
BOX_W = 25
BOX_H = 25

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]

img_grid = img.copy()  # to keep original image for calculations

for y in range(0, height, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, width, BOX_W):
        img_grid = cv2.rectangle(img_grid, (x, y, BOX_W+1, BOX_H+1), GREEN)

cv2.imshow('image', img_grid)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('lenna_grid.png', img_grid)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia:

[image]

---

The same way you can use `for`-loop to get values in boxes and make calculations.

```
for y in range(0, height, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, width, BOX_W):
        x1 = x
        y1 = y
        x2 = x + BOX_W
        y2 = y + BOX_H

        data = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        result = data.mean()

        print(f'mean for [{y1:3}:{y2:3}, {x1:3}:{x2:3}]: {result:6.2f}')
```

Result:

```
mean for [  0: 25,   0: 25]: 155.60
mean for [  0: 25,  25: 50]: 159.80
mean for [  0: 25,  50: 75]: 125.37
mean for [  0: 25,  75:100]: 110.78
mean for [  0: 25, 100:125]: 121.00
mean for [  0: 25, 125:150]: 132.41
mean for [  0: 25, 150:175]: 134.54
mean for [  0: 25, 175:200]: 135.22
mean for [  0: 25, 200:225]: 134.36
mean for [  0: 25, 225:250]: 134.32
mean for [  0: 25, 250:275]: 133.63
mean for [  0: 25, 275:300]: 131.61
```

---

Full code:

```
import cv2

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)  # BGR instead of RGB
BOX_W = 25
BOX_H = 25

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')   # `img` is a `numpy array` (but in BGR instead of RGB)
height, width = img.shape[:2]

img_grid = img.copy()  # to keep original image for calculations

for y in range(0, height, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, width, BOX_W):
        img_grid = cv2.rectangle(img_grid, (x, y, BOX_W+1, BOX_H+1), GREEN)

cv2.imshow('image', img_grid)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # press any key to close window

cv2.imwrite('lenna_grid.png', img_grid)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# -----------------------------------------

for y in range(0, height, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, width, BOX_W):
        x1 = x
        y1 = y
        x2 = x + BOX_W
        y2 = y + BOX_H
        data = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        result = data.mean()
        print(f'mean for [{y1:3}:{y2:3}, {x1:3}:{x2:3}]: {result:6.2f}')
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also draw rectangles without `cv2.rectangle` - you can replace pixels in array

```
    # left line   
    img_grid[y1:y2, x1] = GREEN

    # right line
    img_grid[y1:y2, x2] = GREEN

    # top line
    img_grid[y1, x1:x2] = GREEN

    # bottom line
    img_grid[y2, x1:x2] = GREEN
```

But it may need to check if `x2` and `y2` are still inside image.

```
    if x2 >= width:
        x2 = width-1
    if y2 >= height:
        y2 = height-1
```

---

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)  # BGR instead of RGB
BOX_W = 25
BOX_H = 25

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]

img_grid = img.copy()  # to keep original image for calculations

for y in range(0, width, BOX_H):
    for x in range(0, height, BOX_W):

        x1 = x
        y1 = y
        x2 = x + BOX_W
        y2 = y + BOX_H
        
        if x2 >= width:
            x2 = width-1
        if y2 >= height:
            y2 = height-1
            
        # left line   
        img_grid[y1:y2, x1] = GREEN
        
        # right line
        img_grid[y1:y2, x2] = GREEN
        
        # top line
        img_grid[y1, x1:x2] = GREEN
        
        # bottom line
        img_grid[y2, x1:x2] = GREEN

cv2.imshow('image', img_grid)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('lenna_grid.png', img_grid)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**BTW:** `cv2` can also uses window to select some region (ROI)

You draw rectangle and press `SPACE` to accept. After last rectangle press `ESC` to use regions.

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)  # BGR instead of RGB
BOX_W = 25
BOX_H = 25

img = cv2.imread('/home/furas/test/lenna.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]

regions = cv2.selectROIs('Image', img)
print(regions)

for number, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(regions, 1):
    x1 = x
    y1 = y
    x2 = x + BOX_W
    y2 = y + BOX_H
    data = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    result = data.mean()
    
    print(f'mean for [{y1:3}:{y2:3}, {x1:3}:{x2:3}]: {result:6.2f}')
            
    cv2.imshow(f"Crop {number}", data)
    
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```